# How to solve $injector:modulerr Error in angularjs v-1.8.2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, typescript

Angular $injector:modulerr Error after upgrading to angularjs v1.8.2
I upgrading my application to angular 1.8.2 and upgrated all JS files but in some page i have error like:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

I saw Stackoverflow's answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-injector?sort=active&pageSize=50) but they're not be true for me!
Can evryone help me?

```
var app = angular.module('FormApp', ['ngTagsInput', "isteven-multi-select", "toastr", "angularUtils.directives.dirPagination", "treeGrid", "ngRoute"]);
    app.controller('FormController', FormController);

    FormController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

    app.directive('loading', [function ($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, elm: any, attrs) {
                $scope.isLoading = function () {
                    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
                };

                $scope.$watch($scope.isLoading, function (v) {
                    if (v) {
                        elm.show();
                    } else {
                        elm.hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]
    );
```

I want to waiting for load data from server until the data not prepare but on Form.aspx getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]